# Can someone give me an example of DescribeInstancesPagesWithContext call

Tags: go, aws-sdk

I am trying to use this Go [AWS SDK](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go), in particular function `DescribeInstancesPagesWithContext`. I cannot understand how to use it, having issues with this argument `opts ...request.Option`, it is defined as `type Option func(*Request)`. Tried googling but cannot find any example code. Thanks!

Comment: Those are called [functional options](https://dave.cheney.net/2014/10/17/functional-options-for-friendly-apis). Here's the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=24lFtGHWxAQ) of the talk.

Comment: this actually helps a lot, ty, you can post this as an answer and I will approve it @mkopriva